# Use return subsetted vector value to subset another vector in R

Tags: r, vector, subset

I have one vector storing character strings like so:

```
labels <- as.character(c('site1', 'site2'))
```

Except my vectors stores 100s of sites.  And then I have data frames, named after each site (site1, site2, etc.), that have dozens of measurements.  I want to use for loops to iteratively access and graph values from the data frames.  In doing so, I was hoping to use the value returned from subsetting the first vector to subset the data frame, like so:

```
y1<-(labels[1]$measurements)
```

But I haven't been able to figure it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mget` to get the values from each of the object names in the 'labels' vector.  The output will be a `list`.  We can loop the `list` using `lapply` and extract the `measurements` column (if I understand the code correctly).

```
lst <- lapply(mget(labels), function(x) x$measurements)
```

It may be better to do all the operations within the `list`.  But, if you need to create some additional objects in the global environment (not recommended), we can change the names of the `list` elements  using `paste` and then use `list2env`.

```
colnames(lst) <- paste0('y', seq_along(lst))
list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)
y1 
y2
```

Comment: Your answer was a little too much for me; I got what I need from the first part showcasing mget.  Thanks!